# Aggrid get get name of columns displayed in the table

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I am using vue aggrid. I have 10 columns in the table and all columns are displayed by default. Now the user can select and unselect column from the column panel. Is there a way to get an array of columns which are selected by the user that are displayed in the table.
I tried

```
this.gridOptions.api.sortController.columnController.getAllDisplayedColumns()
```

This gives the array of objects of selected columns, but is there any other way through which we can get the selected columns names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all visible columns by calling that function in your question directly from the [`ColumnAPI`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/)

```js
columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()
```

Comment: Is there a way to unselect all columns at once i.e to hide all columns. I tried with `columnApi.setColumnsVisible(columnArr, false)`. Where columnArr is the array of header fields which I got from `columnApi.getAllColumns()`. But it's not working as the columns are still visible.

Comment: You can create another question. I'll answer that.

Comment: Kindly have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722962/vue-ag-grid-hide-unhide-all-columns-at-once

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly then you are looking for array containing name(display label or columnId) of the columns like

```
    ["column1","column2","column3",...].
```

well you are already on the right track using `getAllDisplayedColumns` method which gives you all the columns displayed in the grid. You can use below method to get the list/array of column names which are rendered in the grid and are visible.

```
    var columnNames = gridOptions.api.columnController.getAllDisplayedColumns().map(function (col) { return col.getColId(); })
```