# Vue Ag-grid hide/unhide all columns at once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid

I am trying to hide and unhide all columns in ag-grid on data change from the parent component.
This is my child component

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col class="text-right">
          <v-btn color="blue" outlined @click="hideColumns">hide Format</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-card-title>
    <ag-grid-vue
      //
    ></ag-grid-vue>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
//All imports of aggrid

export default {
  name: "DetailsTable",
  props: {
    columnDefs: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return null;
      },
    },
    rowData: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return null;
      },
    },
  },
  components: {
    "ag-grid-vue": AgGridVue,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      agModule: AllModules,
      newRowData: [],
      gridApi: null,
      gridOptions: {},
    };
  },
  watch: {
    rowData: function (newVal, oldVal) {
      this.newRowData = newVal;
    },
    columnDefs: function (newval, oldval) {
      this.hideColumns();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    hideColumns() {
      this.gridOptions.columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach((e) => {
        this.gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnVisible(e.colId, false); //In that case we hide it
      });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.newRowData = this.rowData;
    this.gridApi = this.gridOptions.api;
  },
};
</script>
```

In the parent component the `columnDefs and rowData` get's reinitialized whenever the api get's called in the parent component. And now again on the change of columnDefs I want to hide all the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setColumnsVisible()` accepts a number as an argument which is a `Column.colId`. `getAllColumns()` return an array of `Column` so you need to use a for-loop here

```js
const showAllColumn = () => {
  const allColumns = columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach((c) => {
    columnApi.setColumnVisible(c.getColId(), true);
  });
};
const hideAllColumn = () => {
  const allColumns = columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach((c) => {
    columnApi.setColumnVisible(c.getColId(), false);
  });
};
```

### Usage

```
<button onClick={showAllColumn}>Show all columns</button>
<button onClick={hideAllColumn}>Hide all columns</button>
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit blissful-turing-50c9k]

Comment: Why is it that this works when I call the function on button click. But if I call the function on change of another data, this columns are not hidden? Any idea why is this happening. I am using vuejs

Comment: It seems like you didn't assign `columnApi` in `mounted()`

Comment: I'm directly using gridOptions, would that be an issue?

Comment: Actually no, I forgot about that. Will setup codesandbox example to see what happen

Comment: try replacing `@click="hideColumns"` with `@click="hideColumns()"`

Comment: It works on button click. But I want to hide columns when the columnDefs change i.e everytime the columnDefs gets reinitialized in the parent component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220919/discussion-between-nearhuscarl-and-yogesh-kudikala).